# Cox Proportional Hazards - Dealing with unknown values for factors for some individuals in a population

Tags: survival

I'm working on a model with multiple covariates in R. Unfortunately, for one of the factors in the model, the data is spotty and I have a large portion of unknown values. Rouhgly around 30% are NA's. Is it recommended to simply remove these individuals from the model (I believe this is what R does by default, "10,126 observations deleted due to missingness") or to include an Unknown category?

An alternative question, is there a method to recover some of the information they yield for other factors?

Thanks for any advice. If anyone knows of a good source that discusses this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it.